# reading binary data after refactoring of classes

Tags: java, serialization

I have old binary data serialized and stored in a db with an old class 'mypackage.Myclass'

I would like to refactor this class to 'mypackage.topic.Myclass' and still able to read the binary data back (deserialization)

I get an error Classnotfound when :

```
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(bos);
                    o = ois.readObject();
mypackage.topic.Myclass myclass = (mypackage.topic.Myclass) o;
```

Is there a way to force readObject() to match another class then the original serialized class ? Or any otherhint doing this ?

Comment: see ["readobject method throws ClassNotFoundException"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916107/readobject-method-throws-classnotfoundexception).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by creating a data wrapper class called `mypackage.Myclass`. When deserializing the binary data, you can first try to deserialize it as `mypackage.topic.Myclass`. When this fails, deserialize it as `mypackage.Myclass` and convert it afterwards to the class `mypackage.topic.Myclass`.

You can also set the `serialVersionUID` of the `mypackage.topic.Myclass` to the `serialVersionUID` of the `mypackage.Myclass`. If you don't know the `serialVersionUID` of the class `mypackage.Myclass`, or if you doesn't have set the `serialVersionUID`, you can generate the `serialVersionUID`, which is probably used/automatically created by the JVM using this command: `serialver -classpath whatever com.foo.bar.MyClass` (See: [Java - Modifying serialVersionUID of binary serialized object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444909/java-modifying-serialversionuid-of-binary-serialized-object))

When the classes have the same `serialVersionUID`, there will be no error when you deserialize the class.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I wanted to simplify my code and restructuring and avoid creating new classes. So there is no other way to do ?